# Apply a function with multiple arguments on an entire dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'field_1' : ['a', 'b', np.nan, 'a', 'c'], 'field_2': ['c', 'b', 'a', np.nan, 'c']}, index=[1,2,3,4,5])
```

I want to apply the following function on the entire dataframe that replaces each value with something else.

For example:

```
def func_replace(value, n):
    if value == 'a':
        return 'This is a'*n
    elif value == 'b':
        return 'This is b'*n
    elif value == 'c':
        return 'This is c'*n
    elif str(value) == 'nan':
        return np.nan
    else:
         'The value is not included'
```

so that the final product would look like (given that `n=1`).

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'field_1' : ['This is a', 'This is b', np.nan, 'This is a', 'This is c'], 'field_2': ['This is c', 'This is b', 'This is a', np.nan, 'This is c']}, index=[1,2,3,4,5])
```

I tried the following:

```
df.apply(func_replace, args=(1), axis=1)
```

and bunch of other options, but it always gives me an error.

I know that I can write a `for` loop that goes through every column and uses lambda function to solve this problem, but I feel that there is an easier option.

I feel the solution is easier than I think, but I just can't figure out the correct syntax.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try `df.apply(func_replace, args=(1,), axis=1)`.  If you just do `(1)` python doesn't treat it as a `tuple`, where as `(1, )` will be treated as a `tuple` with one element.

Comment: You can also try using `applymap` function. Documentation available here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

Comment: I'd really like to fix your code but I think there's a better way to do this. I'd like to know a little more about your problem before blindly offering you a solution that may or may not solve your actual problem.

Comment: I actually tried what you have suggested but it also didn't work, gave me the following error
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 1')

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your function to operate at the level of each value in a `Series` and use `applymap`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'field_1' : ['a', 'b', np.nan, 'a', 'c'], 'field_2': ['c', 'b', 'a', np.nan, 'c']}, index=[1,2,3,4,5])

df
Out[35]: 
  field_1 field_2
1       a       c
2       b       b
3     NaN       a
4       a     NaN
5       c       c
```

Now, if we define the function as:

```
def func_replace(value):
    if value == 'a':
        return 'This is a'
    elif value == 'b':
        return 'This is b'
    elif value == 'c':
        return 'This is c'
    elif str(value) == 'nan':
        return np.nan
    else:
        'The value is not included'
```

Calling this function on each value on the `DataFrame` is very straightforward:

```
df.applymap(func_replace)
Out[42]: 
     field_1    field_2
1  This is a  This is c
2  This is b  This is b
3        NaN  This is a
4  This is a        NaN
5  This is c  This is c
```

Comment: thanks @sriramn for your answer. It does work as you mentioned but I would like to have other arguments too in the function. You did omit the argument `n` from the function but `n` is vital for me. This example in a simplified example of what I'm trying to do where i can't just not pass the extra arguments i would like too. So is there a way to still pass the other argument(s)?

Comment: Could you please setup a minimum working example where you use the `n` argument? My solution was based on your final `df` in your original question.

Comment: n could be any integer. I would say n>1 in the example I just gave!

Comment: If `n` is static you can curry your function (http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/curry.html) and use the same logic. It is currently hard to see how you set it to be dynamic for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
def func_replace(df, n):
    df_temp = df.replace({r"[^abc]": "The value is not included"}, regex=True)
    return df_temp.replace(["a", "b", "c"], ["This is a " * n, "This is b " * n, "This is c " * n])

df.apply(func_replace, args=(2,))
```